How to close the Spring Context on Fatal Exceptions in reactive chains (e.g. OutOfMemory)
Inside of a Spring Application, we are using the ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient to consume messages from the Azure ServiceBus and processing them in a reactive chain. Something like:
public class MyApplication {

  // ...

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
  }

}

public class ApplicationLifecycleManager {

  // ...

  @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
  public void onAfterStartUp() {
    receiverAsyncClient
      .receiveMessages()
      .flatMap(...) // do some processing
      .subscribe();
  }

}

We've encountered the issue that when the reactive chain encounters an OutOfMemoryException, we get the logs WARN [parallel-5] reactor.core.Exceptions - throwIfFatal detected a jvm fatal exception, which is thrown and logged below: with the stack trace, but we don't seem to have any way to act upon it, but the Spring Application and unrelated chains keep running.
In our case, we need to make sure that the Spring Context closes and the Application is restarted, so that we can resume processing ServiceBus messages.
We tried to manually catch the Fatal Exception, but nothing seems to work - FatalExceptions seem to bypass all onError operators and hooks. Surrounding try/catch blocks also don't seem to be able to catch the error. We would be fine with calling System.exit(), but we don't seem to be able to catch the exception anywhere.

I forwarded the question to GitHub and got this response.
To Quote Darius:

Long story short, we can't handle Errors like Exceptions and propagate them via Reactor's mechanisms. You have to resort to traditional JVM control structures if you want to catch any Error. That is not recommended though and you should allow your JVM to exit as there might be no more memory left to even try to do any cleanup. External control is applicable - e.g. sizing your heap properly, responding to health checks (e.g. using Spring Boot Actuator's endpoint) and restarting the JVM using your orchestrator of choice (e.g. Kubernetes) if there's no timely response to the health checks.

We resolved the issue by using the JVM Flag -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError, which allows the service to exit and K8s to restart the pod.
It may be obvious, as a side note: manually throwing an OutOfMemoryError like throw new OutOfMemoryError("Test error") does not have the same effect as when the error is actually encountered by the JVM.
Local testing scenarion with the -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx512m options:
Flux.range(0, 10)
        .delayElements(java.time.Duration.ofMillis(300))
        .flatMap(i -> {
          if (i == 5) {
            log.warn("Filling up memory...");
            List<byte[]> storage = new ArrayList<>();
            while (true) {
              log.warn("Adding another array to storage");
              // Each array with size ~10MB
              byte[] b = new byte[10 * 1024 * 1024];
              storage.add(b);
            }
          }
          return Flux.just(i);
        })
        .doOnError(err -> System.out.println("### An error occurred: " + err.getMessage())) // Never executed
        .doOnNext((i) -> System.out.println("Got " + i))
        .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("Completed"))
        .collectList()
        .subscribe();

Logs:
Got 1
Got 2
Got 3
Got 4
[2024-04-30 13:26:24.167] WARN [parallel-3] Filling up memory...
[2024-04-30 13:26:24.167] WARN [parallel-3] Adding another array to storage
[2024-04-30 13:26:24.173] WARN [parallel-3] Adding another array to storage
...
[2024-04-30 13:26:24.456] WARN [parallel-3] Adding another array to storage
Terminating due to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space




In our case, we need to make sure that the Spring Context closes and the Application is restarted, so that we can resume processing ServiceBus messages.


To address the issue of handling fatal exceptions, such as OutOfMemoryError, and check that the Spring context closes and the application restarts.

Here, I restarted the application with the below code and resumed processing ServiceBus messages
Code :
ApplicationLifecycleManager.java :
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Component
public class ApplicationLifecycleManager {

    private final ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient receiverAsyncClient;
    public ApplicationLifecycleManager(ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient receiverAsyncClient) {
        this.receiverAsyncClient = receiverAsyncClient;
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void onAfterStartUp() {
        receiverAsyncClient.receiveMessages()
                .flatMap(this::processMessage)
                .onErrorResume(throwable -> {
                    if (isFatal(throwable)) {
                        restartApplication();
                        return Mono.empty();
                    } else {
                        return Mono.error(throwable);
                    }
                })
                .subscribe();
    }
    private Flux<?> processMessage(ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient.Message message) {
        consumeMemory();
        System.out.println("Processing message: " + message.getContent());
        return Flux.empty(); 
    }

    private void consumeMemory() {
        int arraySize = 1000000;
        int[] array = new int[arraySize];
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
            array[i] = i;
        }
    }
    private boolean isFatal(Throwable throwable) {
        return throwable instanceof OutOfMemoryError;
    }
    
    private void restartApplication() {
        System.out.println("Restarting application...");
    }
}

ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient.java :
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

@Component
public class ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient {

    @Value("${azure.servicebus.connection-string}")
    private String connectionString;

    @Value("${azure.servicebus.topic-name}")
    private String topicName;

    @Value("${azure.servicebus.subscription-name}")
    private String subscriptionName;

    public Flux<Message> receiveMessages() {
        return Flux.just(new Message("Message 1"), new Message("Message 2"), new Message("Message 3"));
    }
    static class Message {
        private String content;
        public Message(String content) {
            this.content = content;
        }

        public String getContent() {
            return content;
        }
    }
}

MessageController.java :
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

@RestController
public class MessageController {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient receiverAsyncClient;
    @GetMapping("/messages")
    public ResponseEntity<Flux<ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient.Message>> receiveMessages() {
        Flux<ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient.Message> messages = receiverAsyncClient.receiveMessages();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(messages);
    }
}

application.properties :
azure.servicebus.connection-string=<connec_string>
azure.servicebus.topic-name=<topic_name>
azure.servicebus.subscription-name=<subscription_name>

pom.xml:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-messaging-servicebus</artifactId>
        <version>7.16.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


The onErrorResume() operator catches any exceptions thrown during processing.
The isFatal() method checks if the exception is a fatal error, such as an OutOfMemoryError.
If a fatal error is detected, the restartApplication() method is called to trigger a restart of the application.

Output :



This doesn't solve the issue - the example it doesn't throw an exception, the .onErrorResume does not handle true fatal exceptions (as per spec of project reactor- https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/index.html?reactor/core/Exceptions.html)
